# Why is ContourPlot not displaying this curve?

Tags: plotting

I am using the general form of a second-degree plane curve:

$$Ax^2+2Bxy + Cy^2+2Dx + 2Ey + F = 0$$

I want to randomly generate plane curves of this form, so I am using `RandomReal[{-1,1},6]` to
generate the coefficients. I made the above equation into a function:

```
SecondDegreeCurve[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_}, x_, y_] := 
   a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2 + 2 d x + 2 e y + f == 0
```

However, when I try to plug the composition

```
ContourPlot[
 SecondDegreeCurve[RandomReal[{5}, 6], x, y], 
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

into `ContourPlot`, the image comes back blank.

When I run `SecondDegreeCurve[RandomReal[{5}, 6], x, y]`, I get something like the following output:

```
1.4557 + 5.20582 x + 1.29609 x^2 + 9.37565 y + 6.73248 x y + 1.84528 y^2 == 0
```

and when I plug this into `ContourPlot`, the curve is displayed.

My question is, what is it about the initial composed expression that doesn't display the curve?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `ContourPlot`. Try it with `Evaluate` inserted, like this:

```
ContourPlot[
   SecondDegreeCurve[RandomReal[{5}, 6], x, y] // Evaluate,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
]
```

you get ouput like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That did the trick! So, since I ran the composed function and got the output, that was the evaluation step that I was missing initially?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't  use Evaluate your function is evaluated completely anew for every point the ContourPlot tries. That means the RandomReal is executed every time, yielding a hopeless mess of values. With Evaluate the RandomReal disappears from the resulting function, as only the numerical results remain.

Answer (score 5):

`Evaluate` works.  I prefer `Function`:

```
SecondDegreeCurve[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_}, x_, y_] := 
  a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2 + 2 d x + 2 e y + f == 0

ContourPlot[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] & @
  SecondDegreeCurve[RandomReal[{5}, 6], x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use Evaluate, i.e.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ SecondDegreeCurve[RandomReal[{5}, 6], x, y] == 0, 
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@tab, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).