# Why do I have to put Evaluate[] here

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I wanted to draw some contours. I succeeded with this:

```
W1 = {p, -2, 2, 0.5};
W2 = {p, -10, 10, 1};
P = W1; ContourPlot[ 
 Evaluate[Union[Table[y^2 == 2 p*x, Evaluate[P]], 
   Table[x^2 == 2 p*y, Evaluate[P]]]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
P = W2;
ContourPlot[Evaluate[
  Union[Table[y^2 == 2 p*x, Evaluate[ P]], 
   Table[x^2 == 2 p*y, Evaluate[P]]]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

I don't like this solution. I used Evaluate[] a few times and I feel like it is unnecessary although without the function I get errors. Could anyone explain me that. I find the reference unhelpful (maybe that's my lack of language?) "causes expr to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated.".

Comment: `ContourPlot[]` and `Table[]` both have the `HoldAll` attribute, so the `Evaluate[]` is needed.

Comment: See also the discussions on [MathGroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/JsxBRAUHG3w/X26ItynjBIcJ) with follow-ups [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xSp_AzI30SU/jSh9Oa0zis4J). Incidentally, one of the critical voices there, AES, has recently passed away.

Comment: @jens Thanks for the pointer, I love this part: _Would you
really want to argue that high school students, or freshman students in college, should have to first go through a tutorial in Hold and Evaluate (and maybe also HoldAll, HoldFirst, NHoldAll, HoldAllComplete, HoldRest, SequenceHold, Extract,and Unevaluated) before they could start plotting Lists using Plot?_

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1375/121

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ContourPlot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. That means that it receives its arguments before they are evaluated. So, if you put as a first argument, something that evaluates to a list but it's not a list, it won't fit with the overloaded version of `ContourPlot` that expects a list.
The same happens with the second argument of `Table`. Whether they end up not evaluating, using another overload, giving a warning, or simply taking more time than they should, that depends on the particular case at hand

`Evaluate` is something that makes the containing function behave temporarily as non-holding. Try

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x_]:=Hold[x];
f[2+2]
f[Evaluate[2+2]]
```

If you don't find this neat, what's usually done is use `With`

```
With[{P = P},
 With[{lists = Union[Table[y^2 == 2 p*x, P], Table[x^2 == 2 p*y, P]]},
   ContourPlot[lists, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

You needed `Evaluate` because you want evaluation of an argument that is normally held, both in the case of `ContourPlot` and `Table`.  There are several ways to force this evaluation.

1. `Evaluate` causes evaluation of an argument before the function reads it, or even "sees" it for pattern matching.  It only works at the *first level* of the function, meaning it must wrap (be the head of) an argument, and not a sub-expression.  Compare:  `Hold[Evaluate[2 + 2], 3 + 3]` and `Hold[5 + Evaluate[2 + 2]]`.  (`Hold` is used as a representative of an arbitrary function with the `HoldAll` attribute.)
2. Some functions such as `Plot` (and `FindRoot`) can use the option `Evaluated -> True` -- for these this is superior to other methods because the range variable is still correctly localized.
3. You can use a function which does not have a Hold attribute to cause intermediate evaluation.  The most direct way is a "pure function" using `&`:
   `Hold[1 + 2 + #] &[2 + 2]`
   This works because the `&` function evaluates its argument before `Hold` ever sees it, and `#` (`Slot`) can appear anywhere in the body of the function, not merely the first level.
4. As Rojo stated you can use `With` to do a lexical replacement of specific variables:  `With[{x = 2 + 2}, Hold[x, 3 + 3]]`
5. More complicated evaluations and insertion may be achieved using [the methods I described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6359/121).

Example using the pure function method:

```
W1 = {p, -2, 2, 0.5};
P = W1;

ContourPlot[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}] &[
  Union[Table[y^2 == 2 p*x, #], Table[x^2 == 2 p*y, #]] & @ P
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Rojo actually I didn't try `Evaluated -> True` in this case before posting; I am surprised to find that it doesn't work here.  Oops!