# Problem in Plot at start

Tags: graphics

The derivative can be used to calculate roots. However the same function cannot be plotted.The error is at start point of domain:

```
f[x_, lam_] := lam*(x - 1) (x - 3) (x - 5)/10
Plot[f[x, 3], {x, -1, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}, GridLines -> Automatic]
Solve[D[f[x, 5], x] == 0, x]
Plot[D[f[x, 5], x], {x, -1, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Add `Evaluated -> True` to your second plot.

Comment: Related: [(6894)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/121) and [many others](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22Evaluated%22).