# Plotting equations stored in a variable

Tags: plotting, implicit

The following produces an empty plot:

```
eqn = x^2 + y^2 == 1;
ContourPlot[eqn, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Whereas the following plots a circle, as expected:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

What do I need to do to get the former to work with `eqn`?
My actual `eqn` is a complicated list of equations.

I am sure this is elementary...

Comment: `ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: Ah, thanks! Is there a short explanation of why `Evaluate` is needed here? Is it because `ContourPlot` has attribute `HoldAll`?

Comment: I found an explanation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6896/194). Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you found it.  All commands that plot functions or equations are `HoldAll`. In this specific case, `ContourPlot` sees the unevaluated symbol `eqn` and decides it's a function, not an equation, because the `Head` is `Symbol` and not `Equal`. (I think it could be changed so that `Evaluate` is not needed in this case, but until it's changed, `Evaluate` is what you have to use.)

Comment: @user21: Yes, I linked to that in a comment above. It is a duplicate, and there is a clear explanation there by two users.