# Some confusions about Evaluate[] and HoldAll in Plot[]

Tags: plotting, evaluation, hold

i can't understand the outputs of the three commands in the following picture.

question1:

In my understanding, command one `Plot[Table[a*x^2,{a,3}],{x,-3,3}]` is totally equal to command two `Plot[{x^2,2x^2,3x^2},{x,-3,3}]`, because the result of `Table[a*x^2,{a,3}]` is `{x^2,2x^2,3x^2}`. but why the outputs are different?

question2:

i don't understand the using of `Evaluate[]`. in doc of `Evaluate[]`, the explanation is "Evaluate[] causes expr to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated". And i found one attributes of `Attributes[Table]` is indeed `HoldAll`, in doc of `HoldAll`, the explanation is "HoldAll is an attribute that specifies that all arguments to a function are to be maintained in an unevaluated form."

I fall into the confusion: Are the arguments of `Table[a*x^2,{a,3}]` is maintained in an unevaluated form? In my eyes, obviously the `a` is changing and evaluating. so how to understanding the meaning of "maintained in an unevaluated form"? Why the results of command two is same as command three?

[image]

Comment: hopefully useful hint `// Trace` to see the differences in the three expressions

Comment: The problem is not the `HoldAll` attribute of `Table`, rather the one of `Plot`. See also e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here)