# How to color functions on a graph in different colors when using Table?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, plot-themes

Why are both parabolas of the same color in the first code, and different in the second code? How to make each parabola a different color in the first case and make the corresponding legend?

1.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

y[x_] := x^2;

gr1 = Plot[Table[i*y[x], {i, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 10}]
```

2. 

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Table[i*y[x], {i, 1, 2}]

(*{x^2, 2 x^2}*)

gr2 = Plot[{x^2, 2 x^2}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[i*y[x], {i, 1, 2}],
 {x, 1, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

**See also:**

1. [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/125)
2. [Why do I have to put Evaluate here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/125)

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain why aren't graphs getting different colors without Evaluate?

Comment: Because `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` and its argument must be evaluated to be seen as a list.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thanks!

Comment: see also [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/125) and [Why do I have to put Evaluate here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/125)

Comment: @kglr, thanks a lot!