# Plotting function lists

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in Plot when using Evaluate vs when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate)
>   [Why do I have to put Evaluate[] here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here)
>   [Why is ContourPlot not displaying this curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1375/121)

Why is nothing (empty plot, without error) plotted, when using the following code?

```
 tab = Table[x^2 + y^2 == R, {R, 0.2, 1, 0.2}];
 ContourPlot[tab, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@tab, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Evaluate` here. The reason for this is that `ContourPlot` has the attribute of "HoldAll".

```
Attributes@ContourPlot
{HoldAll, Protected}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to plot the contours of a list of equations. The list of function is

```
{x^2 + y^2 == 0.2, x^2 + y^2 == 0.4, x^2 + y^2 == 0.6, x^2 + y^2 == 0.8, x^2 + y^2 == 1.}
```

With one equation you can use simply

```
 ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 0.2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

With two equations you can use a list as argument of CountourPlot

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 0.2, x^2 + y^2 == 0.4}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

To use your table, try

```
ContourPlot[tab // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]