# How to ContourPlot a Table?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is ContourPlot not displaying this curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/why-is-contourplot-not-displaying-this-curve)
>   [Why do I have to put Evaluate[] here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/121)

I'm trying to plot certain contours of a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

What I tried is the following:

```
ContourPlot[Table[f[x, y] == a, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

For some reason this doesn't work. If I first evaluate `Table[f[x, y] == a, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]` and then plug the result into `ContourPlot`, however, it does work. I've noticed that `Table[f[x, y] == a, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]` is evaluated to `{False, False, ..., False}` somewhere in the process if evaluated inside `ContourPlot`. (Which is not the same result as when evaluated separately.)

> Why does this happen? What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/why-is-contourplot-not-displaying-this-curve, which is a potential duplicate.

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[f[x, y] == a, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` works for me indeed, for some function

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  I am closing this question in light of your comment.  If you find that the answers there are *not* sufficient please leave a comment or flag the question to get my attention and I shall reopen it.