# Why won't this graph?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I'm trying to sketch level curve for z=k for the specified values of `k={-2,-1,2}`
of `z= 4x^2 - 4x + y^2 + 2y`

So I changed this(by hand) to ellipse of the form `4(x - (1/2))^2 + (y + 1)^2 = k + 2`
 then I put in the following code

```
ContourPlot[z + 2 == 4 (x - (1/2))^2 + (y + 1)^2 , {z = -1.99999}, {z = -1}, {z =
    1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourStyle -> Black]
```

but when I try to evaluate cell I get

```
ContourPlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {y,-5,5}) beyond position 3 in ContourPlot[z+2==4 (x-Times[<<2>>])^2+(y+1)^2,{z=-1.99999},{z=-1},{z=1},{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},ContourStyle->Black]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
ContourPlot[z + 2 == 4 (x - 1/2)^2 + (y + 1)^2, {z = -1.99999}, {z = -1}, {z =  1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourStyle -> Black]
```

Anyone can tell me what wrong with this code? Also when its says "beyond position 3" do I count 1 for each comma ?
How can I get it to sketch this ellipse for the 3 different values of k? thought maybe its the -2 so changed it to -1.999 .
I'm sorry if this is really obvious but it's only my 2nd time using Mathematica. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wrong syntax for `ContourPlot`. You'll want the `Contours` option. Also you don't actually need to recast in that form (it shouldn't hurt or help, that is).

Comment: Contours[3 == 
  4 (-(1/2) + x)^2 + (1 + y)^2, {-1.99999}, {-1}, {1}, {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourStyle -> GrayLevel[0]]  is what it returns when I use Contours

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Somebody please improve my answer, utter neophyte when it comes to putting MMA images in answer

Comment: See Help > Documentation Center, enter ContourPlot, then navigate to Options > Contours and look at example "Use specific contours:".

Comment: Related: [(1375)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1375/121),
[(6894)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Evaluate` inside of `ContourPlot` is how I would do it...

```
kVals = {-1.95, -1.9, -1.5, -1, 0, 1, 2};

levelCurve = (4 x^2 - 4 x + y^2 + 2 y)
```

> -4 x + 4 x^2 + 2 y + y^2

```
 levelCurve2 = (4 (x - 1/2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 2)
```

> -2 + 4 (-(1/2) + x)^2 + (1 + y)^2

```
Simplify[levelCurve2 == levelCurve]
```

> True

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[levelCurve2 == k, {k, kVals}]], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -4, 2}]
```

[image: ContourPlot with Evaluate]

Comment: Thank you, but if I only want k= -2, -1, 2 this is all I should need to change in your code?

Comment: what do you expect to see from k=-2? -- I doubt ContourPlot will give you a single point

Comment: Yes k=-2 was part of question not my choice but I just put in -1.9999 and it has given what looks like a point.

Comment: Try -1.999 and `PlotPoints -> 200` to get inner point (almost).

Comment: Yes I did -1.9999 it shows tiny circle that appears to be a point which is fine .Can anybody explain why my code failed? still unsure. First comment said i should use Contours but Manuel --Moe-- G used ContourPlot . So I'm unsure what I should do next time in similar situation and what was actually wrong with my original code. . .

Comment: `{z = -1.99999}` etc, is not a legal argument for `ContourPlot`, which is why it failed.  Note also that you need to delete `z` from your equation inside `ContourPlot`, because it is an undefined (and unnecessary) variable.  `Contours` is an option inside `ContourPlot`. For instance, you could have used `Contours->{-1.9999,-1,1}`.  See the Details and Options section of the `ContourPlot` documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To make clear the explanation in my Comments, your curves can be plotted with

```
ContourPlot[4 (x - (1/2))^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},  ContourStyle -> Black, 
  Contours -> {-1.999, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200, ColorFunction -> (White &)]
```

[image: contours]

It differs from your original expression as follows:

- The equation involving z is replaced by an expression that defines z
- Input parameters `{z = -1.99999}`, etc not recognized by `ContourPlot` are eliminated.  These are what caused the error message.
- `Contours -> {-1.999, -1, 1}` specifies the contours desired.  This undoubtedly is what Daniel Lichtblau had in mind.
- `ColorFunction -> (White &)` specifies that the space between contours is white.
- `PlotPoints -> 200` tells `ContourPlot` to begin looking for contours at 200 locations.  With fewer points it is unable to find the innermost contour.  Warning: too large a number of points can slow your code greatly!

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply I left computers in college. Will try again with this new knowledge you and Manuel  have given me in the morning. Your help and time are much appreciated.