# How to plot multiple functions from a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'd like to get separate plots for the functions in a list, and I'm trying the following, which doesn't work. What is the correct way to do that?

```
Table[ContourPlot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}], {f, {x + y + z + x y z == 0, x + y + z^2 + x y z^2 == 0, x + y^2 + z + x y^2 z == 0}}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(1375)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1375), [(6894)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table[ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[f], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
   2}], {f, {x + y + z + x y z == 0, x + y + z^2 + x y z^2 == 0, 
   x + y^2 + z + x y^2 z == 0}}]
```

Just add `Evaluate`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Table` you could use `Map`

```
ContourPlot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}] & /@ {x + y + z + x y z == 0, x + y + z^2 + x y z^2 == 0, x + y^2 + z + x y^2 z == 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Table`

```
Table[ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate@f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}], {f, {x + y + z + x y z == 0,
    x + y + z^2 + x y z^2 == 0, x + y^2 + z + x y^2 z == 0}}]
```

[image]