# Equation in ContourPlot3D requires Evaluate

Tags: syntax

Why does `ContourPlot3D` require `Evaluate` when `Solve` does not in the following example?

```
Clear[x, y, z, Sphere1, Sphere2]
Sphere1 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 x - 2 z == 0;
Sphere2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 y + 4 z - 4 == 0;
p = ContourPlot3D[{Evaluate[Sphere1], Evaluate[Sphere2]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 
    2.5}, {z, -2.5, 2.5}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.35], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None]
sol = Solve[{Sphere1, Sphere2}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` needs to substitute the x,y,z in the equations. `Solve` does not - it just manipulates their symbols.

Comment: @flinty It seems more subtle than that to me, or maybe I am missing something. Consider that, for instance, `lhs = First[Sphere1]; ContourPlot3D[lhs == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]` works without the `Evaluate`, i.e. something to do with the fact that these expressions are equalities, probably together with the `Hold` attributes of plotting functions, that gums up the works.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Your use of `Evaluate` only has an effect if each argument is passed to another function with the `HoldAll` attribute, which seems to be what happens. The proper way to handle the situation is `ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@{Sphere1, Sphere2},...]`. See [1375](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/why-is-contourplot-not-displaying-this-curve)